# Android: new Fragment crashes on Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I am currently having issues with my `Fragment` when the Screen Orientation changes.
I already tried things like `android:configChanges="orientation"`, but that didn't work.
So the problem is: When the app loads a new `Fragment` inside the FragmentContainer, it crashes with the following Log:

```
>java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{foo.bar/foo.bar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: 
Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment  
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment   
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: 
    Error inflating class fragment   
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment foo.bar.BlankFrag did not create a view.
```

The origin of the Error is the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` method.

Excerpt of `activity_main.xml` that is relevant:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView">
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/FragFaecher"
       class="foo.bar.BlankFrag"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </fragment>
</FrameLayout>
```

`BlankFrag.class`:

```
public class BlankFrag extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    return rootView;

    }
}
```

`fragment_blank.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ScimaBackground">


</LinearLayout>
```

relevant Excerpt from `MainActivity.class`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        boolean firstRun = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
        if(firstRun){
            getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
            new dbconnect(this).updateDB();
        }


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Fragment fach = new FaecherFrag(); //new Fragment that gets loaded

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.FragFaecher, fach).commit();
```

Comment: Also, you don't need a FrameLayout around a Fragment tag since the Fragment tag is already a FrameLayout

Comment: included fragment_blank.xml now @cricket_007

Comment: @EugeneLaminskiy This isn't my question

Comment: So, what are line 13 and line 30 of your XML? Do you really need the `<fragment>` if it is just blank?

Comment: Please add the Activity code as well

Comment: @cricket_007 I ran in some kind of Error/problem when I did not include a first, blank Fragment that was being replaced at onCreate().
Furthermore, this error happens everytime I change the Fragment inside a FragmentContainer

Comment: I don't see a need for a random BlankFragment class. An empty FrameLayout is the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `<fragment>` tag wrong if you want to dynamically load a Fragment

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    Fragment fach = new FaecherFrag(); //new Fragment that gets loaded
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // This should be the ID of a FrameLayout
    ft.replace(R.id.FragFaecher, fach).commit();
```

So, change your XML like so

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FragFaecher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This stopped the crashing, but led into some other problems, that are not related to this error, so I am accepting this answer, because it solved the specific issue.
Thanks